# Installing xgboost on GPU in Ubuntu 20.04: The CUDA compiler "/usr/bin/nvcc" is not able to compile

Tags: ubuntu, installation, cuda, gpu, xgboost

This is my first effort at using Ubuntu.

I would like to install the package "xgboost" onto the GPU in Ubuntu 20.04 to use in Rstudio.
Per the links [here][1] (slide 29) and [here][2], something like the following code in the terminal should work:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
git submodule init
git submodule update
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DR_LIB=ON
make install -j
```

However, here is my terminal output with the error:

```
bill@magicMaker:~/xgboost/build$ cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON
-- CMake version 3.16.3
-- xgboost VERSION: 1.2.0
-- Configured CUDA host compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- The CUDA compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/bin/nvcc
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/bin/nvcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCUDACompiler.cmake:46 (message):
  The CUDA compiler

    "/usr/bin/nvcc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/bill/xgboost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_a68df/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_a68df.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_a68df.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/bill/xgboost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a68df.dir/main.cu.o
    /usr/bin/nvcc -ccbin=/usr/bin/c++    -x cu -c /home/bill/xgboost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/main.cu -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_a68df.dir/main.cu.o
    In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                     from <command-line>:
    /usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
          |  ^~~~~
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_a68df.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_a68df.dir/main.cu.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bill/xgboost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_a68df/fast] Error 2
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:95 (enable_language)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/bill/xgboost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/bill/xgboost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

As a possible solution based on my previous error message [here][3] I found the advice to:

put
CUDACXX=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/nvcc
into /etc/environment so that it is applied when using sudo.

However, because I am new to Ubuntu I don't know how to do that, either.

If it helps,

```
bill@magicMaker:~/xgboost/build$ nvcc  --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, especially if it comes with lots of detail and hand-holding.
[1]: https://jaredlander.com/content/2018/03/AIDeepLearningR.html#29
[2]: https://studymachinelearning.com/install-xgboost-gpu-on-ubuntu-16-04/
[3]: https://github.com/jetsonhacks/buildLibrealsense2TX/issues/13

EDIT TO ADD:  I followed the advice in the comments to install version 11, and now I come up with the following conflicting information.  It says I have version 11, but nvcc --version says I have 10.

```
bill@magicMaker:~/Desktop$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2004.pin
--2020-07-15 20:09:50--  https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2004.pin
Resolving developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)... 152.195.19.142
Connecting to developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)|152.195.19.142|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 190 [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘cuda-ubuntu2004.pin’

cuda-ubuntu2004.pin 100%[===================>]     190  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-07-15 20:09:51 (4.40 MB/s) - ‘cuda-ubuntu2004.pin’ saved [190/190]

bill@magicMaker:~/Desktop$ sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2004.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
[sudo] password for bill: 
bill@magicMaker:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.IOolbDjUq8/gpg.1.sh --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
gpg: requesting key from 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub'
gpg: key F60F4B3D7FA2AF80: "cudatools <cudatools@nvidia.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
bill@magicMaker:~/Desktop$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /"
Ign:1 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:2 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Release
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Fetched 317 kB in 1s (310 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
bill@magicMaker:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:2 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Release
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Fetched 317 kB in 1s (340 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
bill@magicMaker:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get -y install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cuda is already the newest version (11.0.2-1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm9
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
bill@magicMaker:~/Desktop$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

SECOND EDIT TO ADD:
Per the comments, I attempted to make the change permanent by re-entering the commands from 6.1.1. but added /.profile to the second command, per the following.  I must not be using the proper syntax:

```
bill@magicMaker:~/Desktop/xgboost/build$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
bill@magicMaker:~/Desktop/xgboost/build$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}/.profile
bill@magicMaker:~/Desktop/xgboost/build$ 
bill@magicMaker:~/Desktop/xgboost/build$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jun_11_22:26:38_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.194
Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28540450_0
```

This properly shows the right version, but when I close this terminal and attempt nvcc --version it shows release 10.1 again.

Comment: The CUDA 11.0 linux install guide is [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) and you can get to previous versions using a link at the top of that page.

Comment: Your installed version of CUDA (10.1) is incompatible with Ubuntu 20.04. Currently, the only version of CUDA that is qualifed for use on 20.04 is CUDA 11.0. Doing this: `CUDACXX=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/nvcc i.....` will not help. CUDA 9.0 is not compatible with 20.04 and will throw an error of the type you are seeing. Your options would be to switch to a supported Ubuntu version, (18.04 would work, for example), or research how to downgrade your installed GNU compiler toolchain, to use that with CUDA.  The 3rd option (maybe best and easiest) would be to upgrade your CUDA install to CUDA 11.0.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I looked over the installation guide and I may have jumped some important steps, but I tried the following commands: sudo apt update and sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit  It responded that "nvidia-cuda-toolkit is already the newest version (10.1.243-3)"   Do I have any hope other than to wait?

Comment: follow the instructions [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=2004&target_type=debnetwork) where it says "Installation Instructions:".  After you're done with that, be sure to perform [step 6.1.1 in the CUDA 11 linux install guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#environment-setup)

Comment: Thank you.  When I run nvcc  --version it says I have version 11.  However, then I received the same error when installing xgboost at the "cmake" line.  So I closed my terminal, and opened a new one. I am editing my post above to include my terminal output due to the conflicting information.  (Your help is greatly, greatly appreciated.)

Comment: Regarding this: `bill@magicMaker:~/Desktop$ nvcc --version ... release 10.1, V10.1.243` you have not properly followed step 6.1.1 If you do that exactly as described, it will only affect that terminal session.  You need to make it permanent for every terminal session, follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path), then close that terminal, open a new one, and see what `nvcc --version` reports.

Comment: After you have `nvcc --version` reliably reporting 11.0, then I would also suggest setting the environment variable `CUDAToolkit_ROOT` [described here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html#module:FindCUDAToolkit) to make your cmake usage as painless as possible.  Again, depending on how you intend to use cmake after that, you may wish to set that environment variable "permanently" as described before, or use the specified switch: `-DCUDAToolkit_ROOT=/usr/local/cuda/` when you invoke cmake.

Comment: I really appreciate the specificity here, but I'm just not sure what I am supposed to do -- I have edited my post above with latest terminal sessions where I entered 6.1.1 again, but added /.profile per the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217931/discussion-between-baprisbrey-and-robert-crovella).